# Truncate from beginning in Rofi

Tags: scripting, locate, rofi

I'm using this command for a rofi-locate script ([source](https://github.com/gotbletu/shownotes/blob/master/rofi_locate.md)):

```
xdg-open "$(locate $query | rofi -threads 0 -width 90 -dmenu -i -p "locate:")"
```

Currently all long path results are truncated from the end, and the actual filename isn't visible, as Rofi truncates from the end if a line is too long to fit. Is it possible to make it truncate from the beginning?

Basically, showing

```
...h/that/cant/possibly/fit/in/a/single/line/so/it/gets/truncated.txt
```

in place of

```
/a/very/long/path/that/cant/possibly/fit/in/a/single/line/so/it/ge...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can press `Alt + period` to toggle ellipsize mode.

https://github.com/davatorium/rofi/issues/917